# Uploading Json to django model database results in Key Error

Tags: python, json, django, manage.py

I have a custom manage.py command which I am using to upload a json file (a list of dictionaries) to my model. It appears to upload two records fine, but then throws a key error:

```
KeyError: 'headline'
```

My code is as follows:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

def handle(self,*args,**options):
  filename = '/DoJ_Data_01-12-18.json'
  newpath = str(Path(home))+filename
  with open(newpath) as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for d in data:

      q = doj(headline=d['headline'],topics=d['topics'],text=d['text'],url=d['url'],date=d['date'])
      q.save()
```

As far as I can tell the json is valid. What am I missing?

Comment: This was the correct approach. Using dict.get(key) worked.

Answer (score 0):

So based on the comment by Red Cricket, the problem was solved using d.get['headline']. There appears to have been dictionaries without the headline key.